# ERROR Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in

Tags: php7

Debo concatenar el contenido de 2 variables de un clase php de la siguiente manera:

```php
<?php
class BD {
    //conexion con base de datos
    public $cadena0 = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=';
    public $cadena1 = 'idCliente00XX';
    //public $cadena = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=idCliente00XX";
    public $cadena = $cadena0.$cadena1;
    //etc...
}
?>
```

Tambien he intentado de esta manera y me arroja el mismo error

```php
    public $cadena1 = 'idCliente00XX';
    public $cadena = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=".$cadena1;
```

Pero me arroja el error

```
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
```

No se si es error de sintaxis, o es algo que de plano no se puede hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberias realizar esa concatenacion en el constructor de la clase, lo defines de la siguiente forma:

```php
<?php
class BD {
    public $cadena0 = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=';
    public $cadena1 = 'idCliente00XX';
    public $cadena;

    function __construct() {
       $this->cadena = $this->cadena0.$this->cadena1;
   }
}
?>
```